# Finding statistical difference in 3 groups with aggregate metrics

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, multiple-comparisons

Let's say I'm running an ad campaign in 3 channels. I want to compare the cost per conversion (# conversions / total spend) for each channel and determine if any channel's cost per conversion is significantly different than another.

| Channel | Impressions | Conversions | Spend $|Cost per Conversion $ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 9884 | 89 | 2500 |
| B | 9858 | 49 | 2500 |
| C | 9553 | 83 | 2500 |

How do you go about calculating this?

I've aware of one way anova tests but I am confused how it applies here given the variables are aggregated and can't be broken into observations?

Answer (score 1):

Even though I think you have/provide insufficient information, it appears to be more a descriptive statistics issue rather then inferential statistics.